# Verificar valores de una celda e insertar datos de acuerdo a ese valor

Tags: excel, vba

Estoy realizando un cotizador en excel con vba. Tengo una inquietud con lo siguiente: Necesito por medio de una macro, lograr que me verifique el valor de una celda o celdas(dependiendo de cuantos datos hayan insertados) para luego rectificar ese valor en otra hoja del mismo libro de excel y me inserte dicha información a otra hoja nueva. 
[image: Hoja COTIZADOR]
El valor a verificar es el código que se encuentra en la celda L17.

[image: Hoja KIT]

Entonces, la verificación la realiza en esta hoja, y al ser el mismo número insertado en la hoja cotización me pueda extraer los valores de las celdas que tienen una (X) y poder insertarlo en otra hoja nueva. Esos valores hacen referencia a peso, alto,ancho y largo (los datos se encuentran verticalmente, por filas) y son obtenido por la función BUSCARV. Los números de la fila D, hacen referencia al número de fila donde están ubicadas los valores de los equipos (en otra hoja del mismo libro).

[image: Hoja EQUIPO]

De esta hoja se extraen todos los valores de los equipos.

Espero haber podido ser claro con mi inquietud.

Comparto la macro que tengo por ahora. Me permite insertar en una hoja nueva los datos del equipo 1, pero porque así lo asigné en la macro. Selecciona cada valor y lo pega en la nueva hoja, uno por uno.

Sub Macro10()

```
'Selección de cada valor, copiar y pegar en otra hoja

Sheets("KITN").Select
Range("E3:E6").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("DHL").Select
Range("H17").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
False, Transpose:=True
Range("A16").Select

Sheets("KITN").Select
Range("I3:I6").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("DHL").Select
Range("H18").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
False, Transpose:=True
Range("A16").Select

Sheets("KITN").Select
Range("J3:J6").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("DHL").Select
Range("H19").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone,SkipBlanks:=_
False, Transpose:=True
Range("A16").Select

Sheets("KITN").Select
Range("K3:K6").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("DHL").Select
Range("H20").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
False, Transpose:=True
Range("A16").Select

Sheets("KITN").Select
Range("L3:L6").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("DHL").Select
Range("H21").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
False, Transpose:=True
Range("A16").Select

Sheets("KITN").Select
Range("M3:M6").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("DHL").Select
Range("H22").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
False, Transpose:=True
Range("A16").Select

Sheets("KITN").Select
Range("O3:O6").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("DHL").Select
Range("H23").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
False, Transpose:=True
Range("A16").Select

Sheets("KITN").Select
Range("P3:P6").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("DHL").Select
Range("H24").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
False, Transpose:=True
Range("A16").Select
End Sub
```

El resultado es el siguiente: Me inserta todos lo valores correspondientes al equipo 1. 
  [image: Resultado]
Gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué código has probado hasta ahora?

Comment: Acabo de compartir la macro que he usado. Ese código funciona para insertar los datos del primer equipo. Diría que es útil si fueran pocos equipos, pero tengo 24 equipos. Si en la cotización insertan varios equipos necesito que me inserte todos los datos que corresponden a esos equipos.

Comment: No me queda muy claro como traes los datos,. Ejemplo, el rango `"E3:E6"` tiene los valores 5, 30, 11.57923 y 77,426. Y los transpones en otra hoja en la celda `H17`. Pero los valores que veo en tu imagen son 5, 30, 44.7 y 93.9. Esto es confuso. Tendrás que jugar con un bucle `For...Next`. Es ir copiando rangos que cambie el número de fila y columna. Los nº de filas son siempre los mismos, y las columnas las puedes sacar de celdas donde haya una X. Juega con `Cells(nº fila, nº columna)` también. Y no uses tanto select. Puedes copiar un rango directamente sin tener que seleccionarlo previamente.

Comment: Con respecto a los valores, no son iguales al momento de ser insertados , porque en la filas largo, ancho y alto tienen personalizadas las formulas. Pero está afectando el valor solamente en alto y ancho.Que lo estaré revisando.